# Facebook link preview not working

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I am sharing a post from my website at Facebook, but I am not getting content of my page like (image, name, etc)
I am using Cakephp3 and sharer.php.

There is my code :

```
<li><a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=testmobulous&p[url]=https://mobulous.in/vuewa/Vuewa/channel
<?php echo base64_encode(convert_uuencode($channel['id'])); ?>
&p[images][0]=https://mobulous.in/vuewa/Vuewa/webroot/img/
<?php echo $channel['channel_cover_image'] ?>"
onclick="return !window.open(this.href, 'Facebook', 'width=640,height=580')">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use og tags for that, please look up in the [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/). You can test the data which facebook fetches [here](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/).

- og:url - your current url
- og:type - type of your post, article for example
- og:title - title of your post, and your site maybe
- og:description - description of your post, perex for example
- og:image - url of your image (each image should be in a separate og:image tag)

Example of setting an og tag inside the head tag:

```
<meta property="og:title" content="Title of my post | My site" />
```

Comment: Hello friend @spielerds ..i am trying this code ...but it is not helping me ...Please Verify it  
  <meta property="og:url"                content="https://mobulous.in/vuewa/Vuewa/channel/<?php echo base64_encode(convert_uuencode($channel_data['id'])); ?>" />
<meta property="og:type"               content="Vuewa Video" />
<meta property="og:title"              content="<?php echo $channel['channel_name']?>" />
<meta property="og:image"              content="https://mobulous.in/vuewa/Vuewa/webroot/img/<?php echo $channel_data['channel_cover_image'] ?>" />

Comment: It looks good, but the protocol is missing from the url.. `http://` or `https://` should be there.. Or if your site is available through http and https, just put `//` there.. for example, your og:url should look like this: `<meta property="og:url" content="http://mobulous.in/vuewa/Vuewa/channel/<?php echo base64_encode(convert_uuencode($channel_data['id'])); ?>" />`.. also, Vuewa video is not a valid og:type, it should be probably `video.other`, like this: `<meta property="og:type" content="video.other" />`. Did you put these html tags in the `<head>` section of your site? Does this help?